# VB6 Quotes appearing whenever you open the app

Tags: vb6

I have a VB6 Program that saves the text in a Text Box to a File, and When you open it again, The same text will be there, But whenever I re-open it the textbox text now has quotes around it, how might I remove the quotes? code is:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
On Error GoTo NoFile
Randomize

Dim sFile As String
Dim Blank As String
Dim c1Path As String
Dim iFileNum As Integer

sFile = "C:\JPLData"

iFileNum = FreeFile
Open sFile For Input As iFileNum

Line Input #iFileNum, c1Path
Close #iFileNum
Text1.Text = c1Path

NoFile:
If Err.Number = 5 Then
sFile = "C:\JPLData"
c1Path = "No Custom Defined."

iFileNum = FreeFile
Open sFile For Output As iFileNum
Write #iFileNum, Text1.Text
Close #iFileNum
End If


End Sub

Private Sub Form_QueryUnload(Cancel As Integer, UnloadMode As Integer)
Dim sFile As String
Dim cName As String
Dim iFileNum As Integer

sFile = "C:\JPLData"
cName = vbClrf & Text1.Text & vbClrf

iFileNum = FreeFile
Open sFile For Output As iFileNum
Write #iFileNum, cName
Close #iFileNum

End Sub
```

EDIT:
I've answered my own problem,
I spelled vbCrLf wrong, and the I foorgot to add in the BLsnk variable to handle the Quotes :P

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266338(v=vs.60).aspx) says that data written using the `Write #` statement is usually read using the `Input #` statement.

Also: data writen using the `Print #` statement us usually read using the `Line Input #` statement.

You're mixing `Write #` with `Line Input #`, hence the inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

The `[Line] Input` and `Write` commands are quite old statements that still retain a lot of legacy behavior.  It is likely that one of these is adding the quotes.

This simplest fix is probaly just to remove the quotes when you display the text box.  So change this line:

```
Text1.Text = c1Path
```

to this:

```
Text1.Text = Replace(c1Path, Chr(34), "")
```

The `Chr(34)` is the quotation mark character, the `Replace` function just searchs the `c1Path` string for all instances of `Chr(34)` (quotes) and replaces them with nothing (`""`, which is the empty string), effectively deleting them.

Answer (score 0):

`LINE INPUT` reads an entire line of text from your file including commas and quotation marks. Using `LINE INPUT` you can read something like this CSV data sample into *one* String variable:

```
12345,"John Doe","Fake Street",123,"Test Town",900343
```

The entire line will become one String and you will have to split it on your own. The "opposite" statement for `LINE INPUT` is `PRINT`. `PRINT` outputs as String *as is* into a file. That String may contain commas, quotation marks etc.

`INPUT` is used to read separate fields (column values = cells!) from a single line. It expects the format `WRITE` produces. So `INPUT` and `WRITE` go together. Using `INPUT` you can read several variables from a single comma separated line of your file without having to split the columns on your own. You don't have to use `split` or any regular expressions stuff. Moreover, you don't have to do any type casting. `WRITE` and `INPUT` just work together hand in hand.

For example, one could read a comma separated data row like this:

```
Dim Id As Integer, FullName As String, Street As String, Income As Double
...
' Write a few separated fields in one operation:
Write #fx, Id, FullName, Street, Income
...
' Read all the fields with different types using just one line of code:
Input #fy, Id, FullName, Street, Income   ' Read the cell values straight into your variables
```

If you mix the two pairs `LINE INPUT`/`PRINT` and `INPUT`/`WRITE` you'll not get the intended results in most cases.

If you only want to save/restore a single String (whatever commas, ... it might contain) and don't have several fields (especially with different data types (Integer, String, ...)), go for `LINE INPUT` and `PRINT`. Those do not include any field separation processing. The just work with entire lines separated by `vbCrLf`. If you use `PRINT`, you won't need to write any additional `vbCrLf` characters as `PRINT` will include one line break at the end automatically. (If you don't want that line break at the end, put a `;` at the end of your statement line.)

```
' Save a single String
Dim ff As Integer, MyString As String
ff = FreeFile
MyString = "Hello World!"
Open "myfile.txt" For Output As #ff
Print #ff, MyString   'Just write the String without any additional characters.
Close #ff

' ... Later restore the entire line into one String:
Dim RestoredString As String
ff = FreeFile
Open "myfile.txt" For Input As #ff
Line Input #ff, RestoredString
Close #ff
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove string quotes when writting to a file use Print instead of Write.

```
Dim ff As Integer, MyString As String
ff = FreeFile
TheString= "test"
Open "myfile.txt" For Output As #ff
Print #ff, TheString
Close #ff
```